# How to get attribute values inside an XmlElement?

Tags: c#, xml, nsxmlelement

I have an `XmlElement` containing this data:

```
<message from="smithfamily@conference.hp63008-y57/admin" to="admin@hp63008-y57/Jabber.Net" type="groupchat" id="e83Dn-53" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <body>:d</body> 
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
        <offline /> 
        <delivered /> 
        <displayed /> 
        <composing /> 
    </x>
    <delay stamp="2013-08-07T16:53:32.693Z" xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="admin@hp63008-y57/Spark 2.6.3" /> 
    <x stamp="20130807T16:53:32" xmlns="jabber:x:delay" from="admin@hp63008-y57/Spark 2.6.3" /> 
</message>
```

I would like to get the attributes values `stamp` and `from` inside the `delay` element. I have tried several XPaths but I don't know exactly how to use it or if I have to declare a namespace.

Comment: would you consider using an XElement (Linq to XML)?  Then it's just XElement.Attribute("Key").Value

Answer (score 0):

Use `XElement` instead. This will save you a lot of time and effort.

```
XElement xmlRoot = XElement.Load("someFile.xml");
XElement xmlRoot = XElement.Parse("someXmlString");

string stampValue = xmlRoot
    .Element("delay")
    .Attribute("stamp")
    .Value;

string fromValue = xmlRoot
    .Element("delay")
    .Attribute("from")
    .Value;
```

If you have more than one element use `Elements`, but that should be the basics of what you need.

Comment: I can't still access, it returns null. I supposed I have to set a namespace or something like that

Comment: @DarfZon, there should be no reason to set a namespace (I don't even know how you would anyways for reading). Break each of those statements up and put breakpoints. Go line by line and see where the problem is.

Comment: @DarfZon, my first guess is that what you have posted is not the _complete_ xml, and that it is wrapped in something else.